# Automatically call the semicolon of prolog and don't show the trues

Tags: prolog

When you consult a rule in prolog you can press **`;`** and prolog will continue to show the goals for these rule and a **`true`** at the end of every goal, is there any way to tell to prolog to do it automatically from within the rule?

For example, for:

```
distance(a,b,10).
distance(a,c,11).
distance(a,d,12).
distance(a,e,13).
distance(a,l,14).
distance(a,k,15).
distance(b,h,16).
distance(c,h,17).
distance(f,l,18).
distance(g,f,19).
distance(i,k,20).
distance(i,j,21).
distance(j,k,22).

connected_with(X) :- write('Point '), write(X), write(' connected with '),
                        distance(X,C,D), write(C), write('. Distance: '),
                        write(D), write(' meters.').
```

You can run:

```
?- connected_with(a).
Point a connected with b. Distance: 10 meters.
true 
c. Distance: 11 meters.
true 
d. Distance: 12 meters.
true 
e. Distance: 13 meters.
true 
l. Distance: 14 meters.
true 
k. Distance: 15 meters.
true.
```

But to see the next goal you need to type **`;`** , and there are the **`true`** s that I don't need to show.

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Such mixing of side-effects and regular code is very hard to maintain and reason about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap it with one of the meta predicates, such as `forall/2`:

```
connected_with(X) :-
    forall(distance(X,C,D),
           (format('Point ~w connected with ~w. Distance: ~w meters.~n',
                   [X, C, D]))).
```

The reason you're running into this situation is because `distance/3` has multiple solutions, so when after it succeeds the first time, it asks you if you want another solution. You could also use `bagof/3` or `setof/3` or `findall/3` to obtain all the solutions and then walk over them to print them out.

```
?- connected_with(a).
Point a connected with b. Distance: 10 meters.
Point a connected with c. Distance: 11 meters.
Point a connected with d. Distance: 12 meters.
Point a connected with e. Distance: 13 meters.
Point a connected with l. Distance: 14 meters.
Point a connected with k. Distance: 15 meters.
true.
```